# Imbalanced classification with xgboost in python with scale_pos_weight not working properly

Tags: python, xgboost, imbalanced-data

I am using xgboost with python in order to perform a binary classification in which the class 0 appears roughly 9 times more frequently than the class 1. I am of course using `scale_pos_weight=9`. However, when I perform the prediction on the testing data after training the model using `train_test_split`, I obtain a `y_pred` with twice the elements belonging to the class 1 than it should (20% instead of 10%). How can I correct this output? I thought the `scale_pos_weight=9` would be enough to inform the model the expected proportion.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems sketchy: what is y_pred?

+Remember you are better to run a grid search or Bayesian optimizer to figure out the best scores.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33483309)